# How to update contents of an already existing cout statement

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I am creating an application using mySql in c++, the problem is just like we can edit our posts and comments on a website, I want to fetch a cell from a mySql table and want to edit the particular cell.

for e.g: i am fetching a record saying "hey there, this is a test post" and as i fetch the record in my application, the user can update the post to "hey there, this is a NEW post".

Now the problem is, i cannot update a cout statement.
How can I fetch the record, display it and while displaying it, i can modify it's contents?

I've tried using strcpy & saving it in a local string by fetching the record and copying it into the string, but that didn't work as expected

```
void editPost(){
system("cls");
string dummy;
MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "192.168.0.110", "admin", "admin", "search_engine", 0, NULL, 0);
string strBuff[1000];
if(conn){
    int qstate = 0;
    int id;
    cout << "Enter id : ";
    cin>>id;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<"SELECT content FROM se__dbms where id = '" << id <<"'";
    string query = ss.str();
    const char* q = query.c_str();
    if(conn){
        int qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);

        if(!qstate){
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res)){
                    strBuff[1000]=row[0];
            }
            cout<<strBuff[1000]; /*problem over here, 
                                  what can i change in this cout statement 
                                  that it will even display the contents,
                                  and the user can edit it as well */
            ss << "UPDATE se__dbms SET content = " << strBuff << " WHERE id = '" << id << "'";
        }
    }
    if(qstate == 0){
        cout << "Record Updated..." << endl;
        cout << "Press B to go back";
        cin >> dummy;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Insert Error" << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
        cout << "Press B to go back";
        cin >> dummy;
    }
}else{
    cout << "Connection Error" << endl;
    cout << "Press B to go back";
    cin >> dummy;
}

system("pause");
system("cls");
}
```

actual output:

enter id: 1
Hey there, this is a test post //isn't editable
press b to exit

---

expected result:

enter id: 1
Hey there, this is a NEW post //is editable

Comment: There is nothing in C++ to rewrite output that has already been written out. You need a library like ncurses for that. Also, your use of `strBuff[]` is all wrong causing undefined behavior in your code

Comment: was just checking out different ways I could make it work and so used strBuff[], and as you said i should use ncurses, could i use it codeblocks? do i need to import the library? can you share a little more insight?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to make some sort of interactive application that allows the user to edit the values in the table. That does not work by changing something that has already been written to the output. Instead you can prompt the user for a new value from `cin` (like you do for the 'B' button presses). Then you can store the updated value in the table. Something like this (untested code):

```
cout << "current value: " << strBuff[1000] << endl;
cout << "Enter new value (ENTER to keep value): " << flush;
string newvalue;
cin >> newvalue;
if ( newvalue.size() > 0 ) {
  stringstream update;
  update << "UPDATE se__dbms SET content = " << newvalue << " WHERE id = '" << id << "'";
  // execute the SQL statement
  ...
}
```

If you need something that looks more like a table editor (the user can edit data in place) then you will have to use something like ncurses that allows you to read characters at certain positions in the console or even some sort of graphical user interface.

Comment: yes the solution to my problem would be to overwrite the existing cell completely, that was my last option if nothing worked out. I thought that there might be any other workaround to this problem; and as you said I could use ncurses, would that be possible using codeblocks? can I make it to work by just including the ncurses library?

Comment: @SohailAnsari you can't "just include the library" - you have to actually write the code too. The computer doesn't know that you want editable text just because you included ncurses.